# Multiple updates in a single NHibernate HQL statement

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, nhibernate-3

I would like to execute the following two statements at once with NHibernate HQL:

```
update CustomFieldValue set Value = :newVal where Key = 1 and Value = :oldVal;
update CustomFieldValue set Value = :newVal where Key = 1 and Value = :oldVal;
```

I have created one string and try to update it with

```
var query = this.Session.CreateQuery(hql);
// ... set parameters
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

But I always get a QuerySyntaxException.
Isn't this possible with NHibernate 3.3.1 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand why you would want to do this?  Am I missing it, or are the commands you want to submit to the database identical?

I'm totally guessing here, but are you really trying to do something like:

```
update CustomFieldValue set Value = :newVal1 where Key = 1 and Value = :oldVal1;
update CustomFieldValue set Value = :newVal2 where Key = 1 and Value = :oldVal2;
```

It seems to me, that would work?